# User avatar-ACF fields

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta, avatar

I'm running wp multisite and using ACF custom field (user edit) for my local avatar, in my functions.php i added :

```
add_action('get_avatar', 'tsm_acf_profile_avatar', 10, 3);
function tsm_acf_profile_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {

$user = '';

// Get user by id or email
if ( is_numeric( $id_or_email ) ) {

    $id   = (int) $id_or_email;
    $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );


} elseif ( is_object( $id_or_email ) ) {

    if ( ! empty( $id_or_email->user_id ) ) {
        $id   = (int) $id_or_email->user_id;
        $user = get_user_by( 'id' , $id );
    }

} else {
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $id_or_email );
}

if ( ! $user ) {
    return $avatar;
}

// Get the user id
$user_id = $user->ID;

// Get the file id
$image_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'avatar', true); // CHANGE TO YOUR FIELD NAME

// Bail if we don't have a local avatar
if ( ! $image_id ) {
    return $avatar;
}

// Get the file size
$image_url  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' ); // Set image size by name
// Get the file url
$avatar_url = $image_url[0];
// Get the img markup
$avatar = '<img alt="' . $alt . '" src="' . $avatar_url . '" class="avatar avatar-' . $size . '" height="' . $size . '" width="' . $size . '"/>';

// Return our new avatar
return $avatar;
 }
```

This works great on main blog (blog 1), but problem is when i add that users on subsite(blog 2), my avatar field is empty in blog 2, also after that, if I upload avatar on blog 2, then same user on blog 1 get some random image of some random user.

I have no clue why this is happening, any help is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that user meta is shared across multisites but attachment IDs are unique per site, so user 1 has avatar attachment ID 123 on the first site, but on the second site some other user's avatar is attachment ID 123.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

User variables

```
<?php
// Define user ID
// Replace NULL with ID of user to be queried
$user_id = NULL;

// Example: Get ID of current user
// $user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Define prefixed user ID
$user_acf_prefix = 'user_';
$user_id_prefixed = $user_acf_prefix . $user_id;
?>
```

Display avatar

```
<?php $avatar = get_field( 'avatar', $user_id_prefixed ); ?>
<?php if ( $avatar ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $avatar['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $avatar['alt']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Excuse me, how would the complete code look, thank you?

Comment: I gave complete code. There is nothing to add.
You have even example how to get User ID when he is logged in

Comment: How is that get_field() call different to OP's get_user_meta()? And you can see that OP's avatar fields are attachment IDs, not the structure your code is assuming.

Comment: @Rup get_user_meta(); is WP core function, get_field(); is from Advanced Custom Field plugin